Packages that do not update
There are 3 packages that are not updated. How to solve it?
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.


Perhaps this will help What are phased updates, and why does Ubuntu use them?
